# Procotol composition on the same property

Tags: swift, protocols, composition

Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
protocol VCProtocol1: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: VMProtocol1? { get set }
}

protocol VCProtocol2: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: VMProtocol2? { get set }
}

class VC: UIViewController, VCProtocol1, VCProtocol2 {
    var viewModel: (VMProtocol1 & VMProtocol2)?
}
```

What I want to do is composition on ViewController to avoid re-implementing the same code in multiple ViewControllers.

**Edit:**

To be more precise, the problem here is I want my *viewModel* property to be shared between both protocols because ultimately I want to implement something like this:

**- View Model**

```
protocol VMProtocol1 {
    func vmTest1()
}

protocol VMProtocol2 {
    func vmTest2()
}

class ViewModel: VMProtocol1, VMProtocol2 {
    func vmTest1() { }
    func vmTest2() { }
}
```

**- View Controller**

```
protocol VCProtocol1: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: VMProtocol1 { get set }

    func vcTest1()
}

extension VCProtocol1 {
    func vcTest1() {
        // This is the key point, I want to be able to refer to my viewModel property internally in each protocol.
        self.viewModel.vmTest1() 
    }
}

protocol VCProtocol2: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: VMProtocol2 { get set }
}

class VC: UIViewController, VCProtocol1, VCProtocol2 {
    var viewModel: (VMProtocol1 & VMProtocol2)?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not possible. One entity that implements multiple protocols which declare the same property (here `viewModel`) but with a different type is simply not possible in Swift.

The closest you can do is to use a protocol which define the viewModel type as an associated type and provide conditional extensions (it will force you to use a generic implementation).

*Please note that this is a complex implementation that require a good knowledge of generic protocols. I would not recommend using a such complicated design without understanding exactly what you are doing.*

**View model**

```swift
protocol VMProtocol1 {
    func vmTest1()
}

protocol VMProtocol2 {
    func vmTest2()
}

class ViewModel: VMProtocol1, VMProtocol2 {
    func vmTest1() { }
    func vmTest2() { }
}
```

**Implementation**

```swift
protocol VCProtocolBase {
    associatedtype ViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get }
}

protocol VCProtocol1: VCProtocolBase {
    func vmTest1()
}

protocol VCProtocol2: VCProtocolBase {
    func vmTest2()
}

extension VCProtocolBase where Self: VCProtocol1, Self.ViewModel: VMProtocol1 {
    func vmTest1() {
        viewModel.vmTest1()
    }
}

extension VCProtocolBase where Self: VCProtocol2, Self.ViewModel: VMProtocol2 {
    func vmTest2() {
        viewModel.vmTest2()
    }
}


final class VC<ViewModel: VMProtocol1 & VMProtocol2>: VCProtocolBase, VCProtocol1, VCProtocol2 {
    var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}

VC(viewModel: ViewModel()).vmTest1()
VC(viewModel: ViewModel()).vmTest2()
```

The idea here is to rely on generics and conditional extensions to provide the default implementations for the `VCProtocolX`, which is the role of `VCProtocolBase`.

Comment: I think that's what I wanted. I'm going to try it, thanks.